# Was there ever a declarative formal specification of the Java class file format?

Tags: java, jvm

I recall seeing something in Datalog, or was it Prolog, but cannot find it now. Was it discontinued?

Comment: Datalog is a subset of Prolog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES. 
The JVM spec draft, version 3, does it all in Prolog.

[JVMS3-DRAFT-20090512.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20151125171753/http://elastos.org/elorg_files/FreeBooks/java/JVMS3-DRAFT-20090512.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There's [Chapter 4 - The `class` File Format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html) of the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html). Is that what you're after?

Comment: I doubt it.  That is not a formal specification in the "formal methods" sense.

Comment: No, there was, to the best of my recollection, a definition in the form of Datalog clauses.